# Custom Notification now showing in production

Tags: lightning, process-builder, sandbox, production, scheduled-action

I recently played around with the process builder in a sandbox, and managed to create a scheduled event that would send a custom notification to a user. I finally have a purpose for this feature, but it simply doesn't show up under actions in the flowbuilder in production. Picture of the feature in the sandbox attached.

[image]

Comment: You created the action in sandbox but are looking to find it in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature that is new in [Summer 19](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_notificationbuilder.htm). When your production org is upgraded, you'll be able to use this feature in production.